# Python Otsu Threshold of a 2-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, threshold

I wrote an Ant Colony Optimalization code in Python for finding edges in an image.
I based it off a document : http://ohm.ecce.admu.edu.ph/wiki/pub/Main/TotoOppus/ant_colony_optimization_for_image_edge_detection_WSEASConference.pdf

In the end i have a pheromone  matrix size [I,J] (numpy array) where I,J are equal to Width and Height of the given picture that i find edges in.

Now i want to find the Otsu Threshold of that matrix and put white pixels onto black canvas of [I,J] size, in the places where the corresponding pheromones values are bigger then the threshold. Is there a function to easily find Otsu threshold of a numpy 2 dimensional array ?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/filters/thresholding.py#L230) function from scikit-image should work to derive the Otsu threshold for your array, as the `image` input is an `ndarray`.